# How to move image view in clockwise direction to based on current time in android

Tags: android, achartengine

Hi i have created doughnut chart with clock using achartengine but i need slicing border should move for every 15 minutes current time indicator.So i have created one imageview and placed in chart but i need that image view should move based on current time 15 minutes interval.

[image]

Comment: set #alarm service with #broadcast receiver that fired every #15mins let say. inside onReceive() method of #broadcast receiver dynamically position your image view with predefine X,Y coordinates.

Comment: @Radhey How to get predefine X,Y coordinates. Can you please share some sample ?

Comment: Its tricky little bit .can you able to put some view (or small size button)  at 2,4,6,8 etc point inside that #blue and #cream color area ?

Comment: @Radhey let me check

Comment: @Radhey For now i added image view 6,12,18

Comment: ok ,great . now hide (visibility)that #Imageview .and pragmatically detect one of the #image view's coordinate . thats it... you can get X,Y position at 6, 12,18 level and then place your ic_launcher icon pragmatically there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139202/discussion-between-radhey-and-shan).

Comment: Hi i am getting exception       View.getLocationOnScreen()